# AWS Lambda Reached heap limit Allocation failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to read many rows from a RDS MySQL database, but I'm getting an error `FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`. Anyone know how to fix this?

---

**My Lambda function**

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const Knex = require('knex');
//AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const host = //hidden;
const user = //hidden;
const password=//hidden;
const database=//hidden'sys';

const connection = {
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  host,
  user,
  password,
  database,
};

// createaconnection
const knex = Knex({
  client:'mysql',
  connection,
});

exports.handler = async () => {
  try {
    const res=await knex('ALM_AGGR_LQ_201231_210111_0600_A048_V3_75_GAI').select();
    
    
    const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            //body: JSON.stringify(res),
        };
        return response;
   }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

---

**The Cloudwatch logs for the function call**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   timestamp   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                     message                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|---------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1660654927927 | START RequestId: b2783c75-715b-461c-9e45-3b0cd4e69b8a Version: $LATEST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| 1660655028047 | <--- Last few GCs --->                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| 1660655028047 | [9:0x55d25c605d40]    99339 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 9213.5 (9372.5) -> 9213.3 (9372.8) MB, 27.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.402, current mu = 0.385) allocation failure                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1660655028047 | [9:0x55d25c605d40]   100420 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 9213.9 (9372.8) -> 9213.8 (9373.8) MB, 1037.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 1353.9 ms in 299 steps since start of marking, biggest step 15.2 ms, walltime since start of marking 3339 ms) (average mu = 0.402, current mu =                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| 1660655028047 | <--- JS stacktrace --->                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| 1660655028047 | FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| 1660655028050 | 1: 0x55d257982213 node::Abort() [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| 1660655028050 | 2: 0x55d25785dd9e node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| 1660655028051 | 3: 0x55d257bbe502 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| 1660655028051 | 4: 0x55d257bbe7be v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| 1660655028052 | 5: 0x55d257dcda78  [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| 1660655028053 | 6: 0x55d257de003c v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| 1660655028053 | 7: 0x55d257de386b v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1660655028054 | 8: 0x55d257d956bd v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| 1660655028054 | 9: 0x55d257d8c98b v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| 1660655028055 | 10: 0x55d257d8caa3 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Oddball>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| 1660655028055 | 11: 0x55d258066d40 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary> v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NameDictionary, v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::NewInternal<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                               |
| 1660655028056 | 12: 0x55d2580671e4 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary> v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NameDictionary, v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary>, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                        |
| 1660655028057 | 13: 0x55d258067259 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary> v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NameDictionary, v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::Add<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyDetails, v8::internal::InternalIndex*) [/var/lang/bin/node]  |
| 1660655028057 | 14: 0x55d258067799 v8::internal::BaseNameDictionary<v8::internal::NameDictionary, v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::Add(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyDetails, v8::internal::InternalIndex*) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                    |
| 1660655028058 | 15: 0x55d2581bea09 v8::internal::Runtime_AddDictionaryProperty(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| 1660655028058 | 16: 0x55d2586405f9  [/var/lang/bin/node]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| 1660655037369 | END RequestId: b2783c75-715b-461c-9e45-3b0cd4e69b8a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1660655037369 | REPORT RequestId: b2783c75-715b-461c-9e45-3b0cd4e69b8a Duration: 109436.88 ms Billed Duration: 109437 ms Memory Size: 10240 MB Max Memory Used: 10240 MB Init Duration: 376.53 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| 1660655037369 | RequestId: b2783c75-715b-461c-9e45-3b0cd4e69b8a Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted Runtime.ExitError                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Lambda Function specs**

- MB: 10240
- Timeout : 10m
- Ephemeral Storage: 512 MB

Comment: Can you add Lambda env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=10000 then try again?

Comment: Hello Boris, am also facing this same issue. Its really helps if you share any suggestion for this issue.